# VS2013 Additional Include Directories

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am setting up a Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition project to build and debug Wireshark.  The Wireshark source has a complex directory structure, and the include files are spread across directories, subdirectories and subsubdirectories.

In many places in the source there are includes like this:

```
#include <ui_main_window.h>
```

My C knowledge is rusty but I understand that the angle brackets mean that it's for the compile tool (in this case VS2013) to resolve this reference to an absolute location.  I get loads of errors showing that many of these references can't be resolved.  I can add directories in the "Additional Include Directories" field of the Project Properties and this fixes the references.

Now to the question.  Do I need to add every include directory individually?  Can I get VS to automatically descend down through the directory structure?  I tried using a wild card (C:\Development\wireshark*) but this doesn't work.